# Selecting subset of innermost Descendants using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a xml which is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<client>
  <Customers>
    <Customer>
      <Customer_TIN>ABC</Customer_TIN>
      <Cust_PDR>001</Cust_PDR>
      <CurrentBusinessDate>06-13-2014</CurrentBusinessDate>
      <Facilities>
        <Facility>
          <Cust_External_Id>123</Cust_External_Id>
          <FacilityExpiryDate>2014-06-13</FacilityExpiryDate>
        </Facility>
        <Facility>
          <Cust_External_Id>456</Cust_External_Id>
          <FacilityExpiryDate>2014-06-14</FacilityExpiryDate>
        </Facility>
      </Facilities>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
</client>
```

I am using LINQ to XML to select the data at the Customers element but I need to include only those facilities with FacilityExpiryDate > CurrentBusinessDate.

I was able to find this at the Facility level using the below code:

```
(from i in xDoc.Descendants("Facility")
where
     Convert.ToDateTime(i.Element("FacilityExpiryDate").Value) >
          Convert.ToDateTime((from j in xDoc.Descendants("CurrentBusinessDate") 
          select (string)j).First().ToString())
select i).ToList();
```

But I wanted to know if it is possible to start parsing right at the customers level and get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
xDoc.Descendants("Facility")
            .Where(
                x =>
                    (DateTime) x.Element("FacilityExpiryDate") >
                    (DateTime) x.Parent.Parent.Element("CurrentBusinessDate"));
```

Or:

```
xDoc.Descendants("Customer")
            .SelectMany(
                x =>
                    x.Elements("Facility")
                        .Where(
                            f =>
                                (DateTime) f.Element("FacilityExpiryDate") >
                                (DateTime) x.Element("CurrentBusinessDate")));
```

Comment: This does not work. If I change the code as shown below, I get the same results I was getting earlier:                   xDoc.Descendants("Customer")
                .SelectMany(
                    x =>
                    x.Descendants("Facility")
                        .Where(
                            f =>
                            (DateTime)f.Element("FacilityExpiryDate") >
                            (DateTime)x.Element("CurrentBusinessDate")));